# Python [float(n) for n in line.split()] over a file that contains only one column

Tags: python, file, split, line

I have created a python script where I write in a file an array of `V` (volumes) in a column:

```
 import numpy as np

 volume_pressure_energy = open('datafile.dat', 'w') # Open the file, 'w' for writing
 V = np.linspace(62, 72, 5)
 with open('datafile.dat') as volume_pressure_energy:
    np.savetxt('datafile.dat', V, '%10.9f', delimiter='\t', header=" volume\tpressure\tenergy")

 volume_pressure_energy.close()
```

This generates this file `datafile.dat` :

```
 #  volume       pressure        energy
 62.000000000
 64.500000000
 67.000000000
 69.500000000
 72.000000000
```

The next lines of the script try to calculate the `pressure` and the `energy` using functions and parameters:

```
# Parameters
 E0 = -9
 B0 = 7
 V0 = 6
 B0_prime = 4

# Function P(V):
 def P(V): # To use a P(V) is inevitable as the function depends on V
   f0=(3.0/2.0)*B0
   f1=((V0/V)**(7.0/3.0))-((V0/V)**(5.0/3.0))
   f2=((V0/V)**(2.0/3.0))-1
   pressure= f0*f1*(1+(3.0/4.0)*(B0_prime-4)*f2)
   return pressure

# Function E(V):
 def E(V):
   E = E0+ (2.293710449E+17)*(1E-21)*( (9.0/16.0)*(V0*B0) * (  (((V0/V)**   (2.0/3.0)-1)**3)*B0_prime  + ((V0/V)**(2.0/3.0)-1)**2  *  (6.0-4.0*(V0/V)**(2.0/3.0))  ))
   return E
```

Now, I would like to read `datafile.dat` and treat the first column as `volume` data. This `volume` data will enter the function `P(V)`,  and will give me `pressure`. Similarly, this `volume` data will enter the function `E(V)` and will give me `energy`:

```
 with open('datafile.dat') as   volume_pressure_energy: # open the file
   volume_pressure_energy.next() # skip the first line
   for line in volume_pressure_energy:
   volume = [float(n) for n in line.split()] # split the lines 
   # (removes linebreaks, tabs and spaces)
   # convert all items to floats.
   pressure = P(volume) # call my function
   energy = E(volume)   # call my function
   volume_pressure_energy.write('{}\t{}\t{}\n'.format(volume, pressure, energy))
 volume_pressure_energy.close()
```

When running all this script (below I have posted the **complete script**), it says that

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "BM-model-Enth-obtention_data_E_vs_P.py", line 76, in <module>
 pressure = P(volume) # call your function
 File "BM-model-Enth-obtention_data_E_vs_P.py", line 50, in P
 f1=((V0/V)**(7.0/3.0))-((V0/V)**(5.0/3.0))
 TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'float' and 'list'
```

Apparently, there is a problem with the functions. I have runned them separately and work fine, so the problem is that python is not assuming that each line of the first column of `datafile.dat`, contains the `V`, the volumes that are inserted in the functions.

Why happens this?  `volume = [float(n) for n in line.split()]` is splitting  the lines and converts all items to floats, so why this should be the problem?

**Complete script:**

```
import numpy as np

volume_pressure_energy = open('datafile.dat', 'w') # Open the file, 'w' for writing
V = np.linspace(62, 72, 5)
with open('datafile.dat') as volume_pressure_energy:
   np.savetxt('datafile.dat', V, '%10.9f', delimiter='\t', header=" volume\tpressure\tenergy")

volume_pressure_energy.close()

# Parameters
E0 = -9
B0 = 7
V0 = 6
B0_prime = 4

# Function P(V):
  def P(V): # To use a P(V) is inevitable as the function depends on V
   f0=(3.0/2.0)*B0
   f1=((V0/V)**(7.0/3.0))-((V0/V)**(5.0/3.0))
   f2=((V0/V)**(2.0/3.0))-1
   pressure= f0*f1*(1+(3.0/4.0)*(B0_prime-4)*f2)
   return pressure

# Function E(V):
  def E(V):
   E = E0+ (2.293710449E+17)*(1E-21)*( (9.0/16.0)*(V0*B0) * (  (((V0/V)**   (2.0/3.0)-1)**3)*B0_prime  + ((V0/V)**(2.0/3.0)-1)**2  *  (6.0-4.0*(V0/V)**(2.0/3.0))  ))
   return E

with open('datafile.dat') as   volume_pressure_energy: # open the file
volume_pressure_energy.next() # skip the first line
for line in volume_pressure_energy:
   volume = [float(n) for n in line.split()] # split the lines 
   # (removes linebreaks, tabs and spaces)
   # convert all items to floats.
   pressure = P(volume) # call my function
   energy = E(volume)   # call my function
   volume_pressure_energy.write('{}\t{}\t{}\n'.format(volume, pressure, energy))
volume_pressure_energy.close()
```

Comment: `volume = float(line.split()[0])`. `str.split()` will return a list, even if its only one element. So you should get the first (and only) element by accessing the index `[0]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there's going to be just one number on each line, then to read you should do

```
volume = float(line)
```

line.split() returns a list with a single element containing the string on that line. So when you do

```
volume = [float(n) for n in line.split()]
```

You're saying you want a list that contains each element of line.split() converted to a float.

And that's what the error is saying. That *volume* is a list. And you can't divide a number by a list.
If there could be multiple numbers on the same line, and you want the first. Then you should pass the 0th element of volume to the functions for calculating pressure etc.

Comment: +1, Thanks for your comment. I have replaced `volume = [float(n) for n in line.split()]` by `volume = float(line)`, and all the rest of the code the same. But I receive this error:  `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "BM-model-Enth-obtention_data_E_vs_P.py", line 81, in <module>
    volume_pressure_energy.write('{}\t{}\t{}\n'.format(volume, pressure, energy))
IOError: File not open for writing` It should be available for writing since I have declared `'w'` in the second line

Comment: You close the file and reopen it before the for loop, @DavidC. The second time, you don't open it for writing.

Answer (score 1):

You're splitting each line and passing the list comprehension (a list) instead of the number, float, that you should be passing to the methods.

I think what you want to do is:

```
volume = [float(n) for n in line.split()][0]
```

Which could be further simplified to not treat all elements of the split as floats to `float(line.split()[0])`

Comment: +1 because this is a correct answer and it is annoying when people don't leave a comment for a downvote.

Comment: @JuanCortés Thanks for your comment

Answer (score 1):

The error is telling you that you can't divide an integer by a list. I suspect you're confusing lists and numpy arrays. Perhaps you can convert the list into an array using something like [`asarray()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.asarray.html).

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> l = [2.0, 3.0, 4.0]
>>> 1/l
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'int' and 'list'
>>> a = np.asarray(l)
>>> 1/a
array([ 0.5       ,  0.33333333,  0.25      ])
```

Comment: `V = np.linspace(62, 72, 5)` returns `V`, which is already an array, not a list. `ipython; import numpy as np; V = np.linspace(62, 72, 5); V; array([ 62. ,  64.5,  67. ,  69.5,  72. ])`

Answer (score 1):

A more versatile solution is to use [`numpy.fromfile`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.fromfile.html). It handles binary files and reads it directly to a ndarray.

```
volume_pressure_energy = np.fromfile('datafile.dat',dtype=float)
```

See the documentation for more.

Comment: Thanks for your comment